# ASP.NET MVC view model binding: how to populate a collection of objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Until some days ago it was quite easy to manage model binding in my application. I had a view model, called `PersonOfferDTO`, containing a collection of `PersonProductOfferDTO`. (yes, I'm using the DTO as a view model because a view model in this case would be equal to the DTO). Here below a simplified version of `PersonOfferDTO`

```
public class PersonOfferDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid PersonOfferId { get; private set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<PersonProductOfferDTO> Offers { get; set; }
}
```

And here below a simplified version of `PersonProductOfferDTO`

```
public class PersonProductOfferDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid PersonProductOfferId { get; private set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Guid PersonOfferId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
}
```

I was able to populate the `ICollection` thanks to the method shown below (HTML code).

```
<form method="POST" action="/Offers/AddNewPersonOffer">

    <input name="PersonProductOffers.Index" value="myKey1" hidden>
    <input name="PersonProductOffers[myKey1].Quantity">
    <input name="PersonProductOffers[myKey1].UnitPrice">

    <input name="PersonProductOffers.Index" value="myKey2" hidden>
    <input name="PersonProductOffers[myKey2].Quantity">
    <input name="PersonProductOffers[myKey2].UnitPrice">

</form>
```

But during the last days I have increased the depth of my objects tree, so now I have the following code.

```
public class PersonOfferDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid PersonOfferId { get; private set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<PersonOfferParagraphDTO> Paragraphs { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class PersonOfferParagraphDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid PersonOfferParagraphId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<PersonProductOfferDTO> PersonProductOffers { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see there is now one further level between `PersonOfferDTO` and `PersonProductOfferDTO`, and I can't figure out how to perform a "multilevel binding": create a `PersonOfferDTO` with more `PersonOfferParagraphDTO` each one containing more `PersonProductOfferDTO`.

**NOTE**: I don't want to use an incremental index ([0] , [1], ....)... but a string (["myKey"])

**EDIT**

By request, I add the controller here below

```
public ActionResult AddNewPersonOffer(PersonOfferDTO offer)
{
    if (!UserHasPermissions())
    {
        return PartialView("_forbidden");
    }
    var errors = OffersCRUD.AddNewPersonOffer(offer);
    if(errors.Count() == 0)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return PartialView("_errors", new ErrorsViewModel(errors));
}
```

Comment: `name="Paragraphs[##].PersonProductOffers.[##].Quantity"` where `##` are the relevant indexers

Comment: Your DTO and your view model wouldn't be identical, your view model wouldn't contain attributes for `[DataMember]` cluttoring them up and your view model would only exist within your MVC project

Comment: @StephenMuecke I already tried something similar: Paragraphs is istantited, but PersonProductOffers remains null. I'd need a more complete example. How would you write the name of the hidden field? name="Paragraphs.PersonProductOffers.Index"??

Comment: Please can you post exactly what you are using as your view model in your action method.

Comment: @Coulton yes I can. Now you can see the controller.

Comment: I added an other detail in the OP: NOTE: I don't want to use an incremental index ([0] , [1], ....)... but a string (["myKey"])

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate them with your own keys, you can define your collections within your view model as a `Dictionary<string, YOURCLASS>`it accepts a non-integer index value.

Example view model with Dictionary:

```
public class ViewModelTest
{
   public Dictionary<string, Class1> Values { get; set; }
}
```

Example class to be used in the dictionary collection:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public Dictionary <string, Class2> MoreValues { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public int AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a form that populates the values:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" name="Values[yourkey1].MyProperty" />
    <input type="text" name="Values[yourkey1].MoreValues[anotherKey1].AnotherProperty" />

    <input type="text" name="Values[yourkey2].MyProperty" />
    <input type="text" name="Values[yourkey2].MoreValues[anotherKey2].AnotherProperty" />

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Instead of writing your `input` tags yourself, you can use the helper methods and enjoy intellisense, assuming that you have your view model defined within the view with the same structure defined in your action method:

```
@model ViewModelTest

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Values[yourkey1].MyProperty)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Values[yourkey1].MoreValues[anotherKey1].AnotherProperty)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Values[yourkey2].MyProperty)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Values[yourkey2].MoreValues[anotherKey2].AnotherProperty)

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

You'll have to introduce a view model for this of course and not just get away with using your DTO ;).

PS: A DTO shouldn't be used as a domain model either, it's for transporting information around your layers.

Comment: Thanks, but the example you provide is more simple than what I have to do. In your example you simply have a collection of Class1.

In my case (if you check) I have ClassA which contains a collection of ClassB, and each ClassB contains a collection of ClassC.

And by the way, are you sure that the dot before the brackets [] is necessary?

Comment: Ok thanks. But sorry, why do I have to use a Dictionary? If you check here: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

... there is an example which uses no dictioinaries at all... you only need a hidden field. 
I used that method until some days ago, but now that my application is more complex I can't figure out what would be the name of the hidden field...

Comment: You could also use a List<>.  Any property that is indexable by a value other than an int.  If you're struggling to work out the names, use the helper classes and that will provide you with intellisense.  I'll add these to the answer.

Comment: Bingo, got there in the end.  I hope it helps!

Comment: Oh, a hidden field isn't required at all, it can be any form field.

Comment: Did you test your example? Because I tried similar things and it didn't work. Now I check that what I was trying to do is not different from your example. Note that in my case I have an ICollection<T>, not a List<T>... does ICollection<T> works properly for this pattern?

Comment: Sorry, in my case doesn't work.

This is an example of a name of an input: 

This is my javascript code, which creates an input with my ElementBuilder. Do you see anything wrong in the name?

 new ElementBuilder("input").withName("Paragraphs[prova].PersonProductOffers[" + elt.ProductId + "].UnitPrice").withAttribute("type", "number").withClass("unitPriceInput").getElement()

Comment: If you're attempting to bind to type ICollection it won't work.  I've just found that List<> won't work either.  I have tested Dictionary and that definitely works.